# Why don't simulated t-statistics seem to have the non-central t-distribution described in the literature?

Tags: python, t-test

I am completely baffled.

I'm interested in generating p-values, and specifically p-values for the t test statistic. One slow approach to doing this would be to generate samples of individual observations and calculate the test statistic directly ("observation based sampling"), which can then be used compute the p-value. A faster approach would be to appeal to the distribution of the test statistic and sample directly from the non-central t-distribution. However, these two approaches don't seem to produce test statistics of the same distribution.

Below is some Python code, and you can clearly see that for any value of σ, N, and any non-zero value of δ the distributions do not match.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import nct

REPLICATIONS = 10000
N = 100
σ = 1
δ = 1


# Observation based sampling
data = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=σ, size=(2, REPLICATIONS, N))
data[1, :, :] += δ

null, alt = data.mean(axis=-1)
diff = alt - null

pooled_sample_var = data.var(ddof=1, axis=-1).mean(axis=0)

t_obs = diff / np.sqrt(2 * pooled_sample_var / N)

# Direct sampling
t_rvs = nct.rvs(nc=np.sqrt(N) * δ / σ, df=2*(N-1), size=REPLICATIONS)

# Comparison
print(t_obs.mean(), t_rvs.mean())
print(t_obs.var(), t_rvs.var())

plt.hist([t_obs, t_rvs], bins=20)
```

I have checked my code dozens of times at this point and I cannot find the inconsistency. Does anyone know why empirical t-statistics wouldn't follow the non-central t-distribution that's described in the literature? (See [Section 2.2](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X0400400205), as well as the Wikipedia article sections linked [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Equal_sample_sizes_and_variance) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_t-distribution#Use_in_power_analysis))

[image: Comparison of the "observation" based t-statistics and the directly sample t-statistics]

Comment: Should there be a `sqrt(2)` multiplying the $\sigma$ in the denominator of the `Direct Sampling` `nc` parameter expression?

Comment: THAT WAS IT! Oh my god I spent so much time on this. Thank you!

Comment: Ha ha!  Believe me, that's happened to all of us!